# Is there a way to find the intersection of two rectangles given their current velocity and position in constant time?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, algorithms, physics

Suppose I have two rectangles, let's define them as $R_1$ and $R_2$, which each contain a length and width. Given the headings $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ respectively, as well as the coordinates $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$ and constant velocity $v_1, v_2$ is there a feasible way to determine the collision points in constant or logarithmic time?

My idea so far is as follows: we can perform ternary search on the first collision time - assuming that the collisions are unimodal, which means that there will be a range $[a, b]$ such that the rectangles would be intersecting each other, which I have no proof for. Then, calculate the first time, and thus intersection points as well as locations from there. The running time of this algorithm would be $\mathcal{O}(\log N)$.

[A setup of the rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grpUM.jpg)

Comment: Determine the intersection of the "closest corners" and the time that each rectangle will take for its corner to reach that point; the longer time will be the intersection time, and the positions of the rectangles at that time will be your result.  Similarly there will be a related point which is the last moment of intersection from the two corners furthest from each other.

Comment: The rectangles may also meet at unexpected sides, so be ready to have a test for non-intersection for the above approach and try a trailing-side intersection test.

Comment: You might find this article interesting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: Thanks @abiessu . I am almost certain your approach is valid. By any chance, would you be able to provide insight onto applying this algorithm onto a polyline (the rectangle moves on a polyline, and has new heading on each polyline with interpolated values)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how polylines work, so I can't comment just yet on that.  If they are sets of line segments joined at endpoints, I would guess that each segment could be treated to the above approach separately, but beyond that I'd have to do some research.

Comment: In the figure, it appears that the rectangle is aligned with its direction of motion; the direction of motion is parallel to a side of the rectangle. Will that generally be true?

Comment: @DavidK yes this will always be true. The idea stems from a robot application.

Answer (score 1):

Use a coordinate system where the larger rectangle is always $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$.

Then you only need to check if any of the four vertices of the smaller rectangle ever intersect with that square in that coordinate system.

Comment: To clarify, to account for the changing movement between the two, should I add the vectors together (with one complement) to [compensate](https://imgur.com/ewXjUwm)?